# React Semantic UI Input not firing function on backspace pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a form using semantic UI.
I am disabling the submit button if one of my buttons is not fulfilled.

```
<Button
   disabled={!merchantId || !conduit || !region || !acquirer || !processingTimezone}
   content={`Associate to Domain ${DomainData.domain}`}
   onClick={() => this.submitNewMerchant()}
/>
```

and I am changing the state of each field using a function

```
// other inputs
<Form.Input
   name="processingTimezone"
   onKeyDown={() => console.log('backspace')}
   onChange={e => this.inputChange(e)}
   label="processingTimezone" 
   defaultValue={processingTimezone}
/>


inputChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
}
```

As you can see I am trying to track the user input both using onChange and onKeyDown, but the problem happens if the user focus an input, select all (ctrl + a) and press Backspace.
The state is not being updated to empty or '' or any other value.

How can I manage this ?

Comment: The code works fine for me.

Comment: @nithin where are u testing ? u have a link ?

Comment: Does the state updates for other key presses? Of that input?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sematic-ui-examples-3e17zd?file=index.js

Comment: @AtinSingh yes, they updated correctly.

Comment: @nithin you're right. its working the problem might be something different.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value to the input text :

```
<Form.Input
      name="processingTimezone"
      onKeyDown={() => console.log('backspace')}
      onChange={e => this.inputChange(e)}
      label="processingTimezone" 
      defaultValue="CST"
      value={this.state.processingTimezone}
    />
```

at least the input won't budge if the state doesn't change.